# I want to call a child window but carry on execution of the main code when it returns but my simple program does not continue

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

Here is my code. The two GUIs I created with Qt designer each has one push button. After starting the main code and pushing the button the call to sayHello runs and then the second window appears. I want to stop the sayHello code running until after I return from the child window. Pressing the button in the child window returns to main code but nothing else happens.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import uic

#load both ui files
uifile_1 = 'main.ui'
form_1, base_1 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_1)
uifile_2 =  'child.ui'
form_2, base_2 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_2)

class MainPage(base_1, form_1):
def __init__(self):
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import uic

#load both ui files
uifile_1 = 'main.ui'
form_1, base_1 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_1)
uifile_2 =  'child.ui'
form_2, base_2 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_2)

class MainPage(base_1, form_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButtonCallChild.clicked.connect(self.change)
    def change(self):
        self.main = ChildPage()
        self.main.show()
        self.sayHello()
    def sayHello(self): 
            print('Hello')
            return
        
class ChildPage(base_2, form_2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButtonSelectSheetOK.clicked.connect(self.byebye)
    def byebye(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainPage()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The easiest option would be to make `ChildPage` a subclass of `QDialog`, and use `self.main.exec()` to show the child window in `MainPage.change`.

Comment: Hi This seems a great suggestion as I used a simple  Dialog box before and it worked but I need a more complex window.. I'm not sure exactly how to implement this though. I tried just adding Qdialog in my definition of ChildPage and changed self.main.exec(). But the program  seems to hang after returning to the main window  and the print('Hello') only runs after I close the main window? Any more help I would really appreciated

Comment: I changed my basic layout for my child window to a 'dialog with buttons' in QtDesigner and now it works! Many thanks for your suggestions